# jquery update the object data value dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**url**

```
http://localhost/news-events/news.html?file=hosted_service.pdf
```

**Js code**

```
parseURL : function() {
var _path = window.location.pathname;
console.log(_path);
var _locationSearch = location.search;
var _locationParse = _locationSearch.replace('?file=','');
console.log(_locationParse);
var filePath = "/pdffiles/"+_locationParse ; // /pdffiles/hosted_service.pdf
$('.divEmbed object').data(filePath); **How to set the data of object? this is wrong**
console.log(filePath);
}
```

**Html**

```
<div class="divEmbed">
                <object data="" type="application/pdf">
                    alt : It appears you don't have a PDF plugin for this browser.
                    Click <a href="">here</a> to Download the file.
                </object>
            </div>
```

What would the syntax be if i want to add the data of the object = filepath

Comment: `$('.divEmbed object').attr('data', filePath);`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're setting jQuery's data object, when in fact what you want is to change an ordinary attribute. Use this instead:

```
$('.divEmbed object').attr('data', filePath);
```